# RedShift - How to filter records in a table by a composite Primary Key?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm writing a script for removing duplicates in a RedShift table. But since the table has a composite primary key containing of 2 columns I faced a problem while selecting and filtering values.

Here is what I've implemented so far. It would be easy if I had just one column as a PK but how to achieve the same result for a composite key (`sale_id, sale_date`)?
Especially problematic is the second step - copying distinct rows with a WHERE condition for a composite key into a new table.

**Step 1**

```
-- Saving PKs with dupes into a TEMP TABLE
CREATE TEMP TABLE main.duplicate_sales AS
SELECT sale_id, sale_date
FROM main.sales
WHERE sale_date=2019-05-20
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

**Step 2**

```
-- Copy distinct rows for the above PKs to a new table
CREATE TEMP TABLE main.sales_new(LIKE main.sales);

INSERT INTO main.sales_new
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM main.sales
WHERE sale_id, sale_date IN(
     SELECT sale_id, sale_date
     FROM main.duplicate_sales
);
```

**UPD:** The table is very big so I want to avoid selecting all records. After copy of distinct records into a new table(Step 2) I delete duplicate rows from the original table(Step 3) and then insert distinct records from a new table(Step 4).

**Step 3**

```
-- Delete all rows that contain duplicates
DELETE FROM main.sales
WHERE sale_id, sale_date IN(
     SELECT sale_id, sale_date
     FROM main.duplicate_sales
);
```

**Step 4**

```
-- Insert back distinct records
INSERT INTO main.sales
SELECT *
FROM main.sales_new;
```

Comment: could you please share your sample data

Comment: I am confused.  If two columns are a primary key, then they *are* unique.  Are you saying that you have two columns that you *want* to be unique but are not?

Comment: @GordonLinoff PKs in RedShift do not guarantee absence of duplicate records. I just need to clean up the historical data

Answer (score 0):

what about just taking the distinct value of `sale_id, sale_date`

```
create table table_name_new as select distinct sale_id, sale_date
                 from main.sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am rather confused by your question and what happens to the rest of the columns.  However, `EXISTS` might be sufficient to replace your current second step:

```
INSERT INTO main.sales_new
    SELECT DISTINCT s.*
    FROM main.sales s
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM main.duplicate_sales ds
                  WHERE ds.sale_id = s.sale_id AND
                        ds.sale_date = s.sale_date
                 );
```